Facebook Sharing Debugger reports HTTP error for Open Graph meta tags
I'm encountering an issue with Facebook's Sharing Debugger tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) when trying to debug URLs from my website. The debugger consistently reports an error related to HTTP status code 418:
"Incorrect response code (418). The URL returned an HTTP response code with an error."
my website url: https://sewing-world.shop
meta tags code :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Мир шитья Душанбе">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://sewing-world.shop">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://sewing-world.shop/assets/shadowed_logo.png">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Первый интернет магазин в Таджикистане по продаже швейного оборудования и аксессуаров. Доставка по всей стране.">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="sewing-world.shop">


Issue: The debugger tool indicates that my URL returns an erroneous HTTP status code, preventing it from correctly reading and interpreting the Open Graph meta tags on my web pages.

Attempts: I've tried implementing Laravel middleware to ensure that requests from Facebook's crawler ('facebookexternalhit' User-Agent) consistently receive a 200 OK status code. However, this hasn't resolved the issue.

Alternative Approaches Considered: I've also considered whitelisting User-Agents, implementing dynamic rendering, and adjusting server configurations (e.g., .htaccess rules) to ensure proper access to URLs containing Open Graph meta tags.



I tried the URL for your site on the W3C Markup Validation tool and it responded with an error message: 500 Can't connect to sewing-world.shop:443 (certificate verify failed). W3C recommends checking that your domain records are correct.
